# Trying to use read or readlines method on a result from a function causing a AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror

I need some guidance as I am getting confused to why I cannot perform a method on the result of a function.

would appreciate any help. thanks

import sys

```
import sys

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """This function opens a file."""
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("unable to open the file", file_name, "ending program. \n", e)
        input("\n\nPress Enter to Exit")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

open_file('/users/stefan_trinh1991/documents/programming/python/py3e_source/chapter07/trivia.txt','r')
testfile = open_file
print(testfile.read())
```

it causes the following error to come up.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stefan_trinh1991/Documents/Programming/Python/VS CWD/Trivia Challenge Game.py", line 48, in 
    print(testfile.read())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: You need to learn how return values work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You returned the file handle `the_file` to your main program, but the main program ignored the handle.  You then set `testfile` to refer to the *function object* `open_file`.  The function object does not have a `read` method, hence the error.

Try this repair as your main block of code:

```
testfile = open_file('/users/stefan_trinh1991/documents/programming/python/py3e_source/chapter07/trivia.txt','r')
print(testfile.read())
```

Comment: thank you much appreciate just got a little cross confused.